# how to provide html/js widget for users

Tags: javascript, html, widget

How can I share html/js widget? Javascript, iframe or what way is good?

Now I have html page, css file and js file. I want to share this widget with people so they can attach it to their blogs, websites etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example using java script.

contents of *www.foo.com/test.js*:

```
document.write('<p>some example content</p>');
```

copy/paste widget for *test.js*:

```
<scirpt type="text/javascript" src="http://www.foo.com/text.js"></scirpt>
```

Answer (score 1):

iFrame for non-technical integration. That way you can just offer them a code snippet to copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

If your widget is a fixed size, then the iframe approach is probably the most straight forward.  If you can offer it via a webservice that can be called from a remote client, that's nicer from a developer perspective, but an iframe is probably what you're looking for.  It's how typical banners etc are done.

I would suggest integrating any JS and CSS that you can into your page to reduce the remote calls, if your widget doesn't change a lot... this will help a bit, or at least merge and minify your js and css into a single file each.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna do something like this...

function **addWidget**(element){

//Create your widget here

element.innerHTML = {your widget}

}

The function can be called like this

**addWidget**(document.getElementById("someID"));

Answer (score 0):

Take a look how Google do it with their latest asynchronous code for Google Analytics tracking. Basically it involves your users inserting a short JavaScript snippet in their pages. The snippet dynamically inserts a `<script>` element in the HTML page's `<head>` element that points to a JS file you've written that creates the requisite HTML.

[Google Async code](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncTracking.html)